# Sitting younger, older alternately.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In a group of eight friends, everyone is of different age. Everyone decided to take a seat by an eight-person round table. The youngest of them sat at seat 1. Later they sat: older, younger, older, younger, etc. [seat 2 is older than seat 1, seat 3 is younger than seat 2, ..., seat 1 is younger than seat 8] How many ways can they sit?

Actually, I feel this is the hardest of all the problems I have posted recently.

My first fhought was that you have to split them evenly into the "younger" and "older" groups, but you can find solutions that satisfy the requirements but don't follow this rule.

What is true though, is you cannot the currently youngest person as the "older" one or currently olders person as the "younger" one.
Since it is an archival local math contest, I know the answer is supposed to be 272.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once the youngest has sat, the other seven people form a line of alternating age comparisons:
$$1<A>B<C>D<E>F<G>1$$
It is well-known that the number of ways to arrange the other seven people in such a line is given by the [up/down number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_permutation) $A_7=272$. The Wikipedia page linked describes a simple recurrence for these numbers.

Comment: Thanks.  I really learned something here.

Comment: Actually this is just AWESOME. I hate combinatorics cause it is just about knowing a lot of different interesting series.

Comment: I LOVE combinatorics, because just a few key principles allow you to *DERIVE* a lot of interesting series... and solve numerous problems.

Comment: I didn't want to insult anyone. Combinatorics is just demanding. There is no boredom even if you work with it for a while, but it is frustrating that you rarely have a clear idea what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach which does not require identifying this problem as "calculating $A_7$" and then either copying its value from somewhere or proving any of the recursive formulas for up-down numbers on one's own: List all of the possible ways of the people sitting down explicitly:

Let's enumerate people as $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$, going from youngest to oldest. Then what we want is to find sequences $a_1a_2\cdots a_8$ with the following properties:

- $a_1=1$
- $a_j>a_{j-1}$ if $j$ is even
- $a_j<a_{j-1}$ if $j$ is odd.

Such a sequence gives us a way of people sitting down: $a_j$ sits at the $j$-th place.

The following Octave code generates all such sequences in a file "list.txt":

```
P=perms([2 3 4 5 6 7 8]);

text='';

for i=1:size(P)(1)
    if P(i,1)>P(i,2) && P(i,2)<P(i,3) && P(i,3)>P(i,4) && P(i,4)<P(i,5) && P(i,5)>P(i,6) && P(i,6)<P(i,7)
        text=[text sprintf('\n') int2str(1)];
        for j=1:7
            text=[text ', ' int2str(P(i,j))];
        endfor
    endif
endfor

filetowrite=fopen(['list.txt'],'w');
fprintf(filetowrite,text);

fclose(filetowrite);
```

which are

```
1, 8, 6, 7, 4, 5, 2, 3
1, 8, 6, 7, 3, 5, 2, 4
1, 8, 6, 7, 3, 4, 2, 5
1, 8, 6, 7, 2, 5, 3, 4
1, 8, 6, 7, 2, 4, 3, 5
1, 8, 5, 7, 4, 6, 2, 3
1, 8, 5, 7, 3, 6, 2, 4
1, 8, 5, 7, 3, 4, 2, 6
1, 8, 5, 7, 2, 6, 3, 4
1, 8, 5, 7, 2, 4, 3, 6
1, 8, 5, 6, 4, 7, 2, 3
1, 8, 5, 6, 3, 7, 2, 4
1, 8, 5, 6, 3, 4, 2, 7
1, 8, 5, 6, 2, 7, 3, 4
1, 8, 5, 6, 2, 4, 3, 7
1, 8, 4, 7, 5, 6, 2, 3
1, 8, 4, 7, 3, 6, 2, 5
1, 8, 4, 7, 3, 5, 2, 6
1, 8, 4, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5
1, 8, 4, 7, 2, 5, 3, 6
1, 8, 4, 6, 5, 7, 2, 3
1, 8, 4, 6, 3, 7, 2, 5
1, 8, 4, 6, 3, 5, 2, 7
1, 8, 4, 6, 2, 7, 3, 5
1, 8, 4, 6, 2, 5, 3, 7
1, 8, 4, 5, 3, 7, 2, 6
1, 8, 4, 5, 3, 6, 2, 7
1, 8, 4, 5, 2, 7, 3, 6
1, 8, 4, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7
1, 8, 3, 7, 5, 6, 2, 4
1, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6, 2, 5
1, 8, 3, 7, 4, 5, 2, 6
1, 8, 3, 7, 2, 6, 4, 5
1, 8, 3, 7, 2, 5, 4, 6
1, 8, 3, 6, 5, 7, 2, 4
1, 8, 3, 6, 4, 7, 2, 5
1, 8, 3, 6, 4, 5, 2, 7
1, 8, 3, 6, 2, 7, 4, 5
1, 8, 3, 6, 2, 5, 4, 7
1, 8, 3, 5, 4, 7, 2, 6
1, 8, 3, 5, 4, 6, 2, 7
1, 8, 3, 5, 2, 7, 4, 6
1, 8, 3, 5, 2, 6, 4, 7
1, 8, 3, 4, 2, 7, 5, 6
1, 8, 3, 4, 2, 6, 5, 7
1, 8, 2, 7, 5, 6, 3, 4
1, 8, 2, 7, 4, 6, 3, 5
1, 8, 2, 7, 4, 5, 3, 6
1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5
1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 5, 4, 6
1, 8, 2, 6, 5, 7, 3, 4
1, 8, 2, 6, 4, 7, 3, 5
1, 8, 2, 6, 4, 5, 3, 7
1, 8, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 5
1, 8, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4, 7
1, 8, 2, 5, 4, 7, 3, 6
1, 8, 2, 5, 4, 6, 3, 7
1, 8, 2, 5, 3, 7, 4, 6
1, 8, 2, 5, 3, 6, 4, 7
1, 8, 2, 4, 3, 7, 5, 6
1, 8, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 7
1, 7, 6, 8, 4, 5, 2, 3
1, 7, 6, 8, 3, 5, 2, 4
1, 7, 6, 8, 3, 4, 2, 5
1, 7, 6, 8, 2, 5, 3, 4
1, 7, 6, 8, 2, 4, 3, 5
1, 7, 5, 8, 4, 6, 2, 3
1, 7, 5, 8, 3, 6, 2, 4
1, 7, 5, 8, 3, 4, 2, 6
1, 7, 5, 8, 2, 6, 3, 4
1, 7, 5, 8, 2, 4, 3, 6
1, 7, 5, 6, 4, 8, 2, 3
1, 7, 5, 6, 3, 8, 2, 4
1, 7, 5, 6, 3, 4, 2, 8
1, 7, 5, 6, 2, 8, 3, 4
1, 7, 5, 6, 2, 4, 3, 8
1, 7, 4, 8, 5, 6, 2, 3
1, 7, 4, 8, 3, 6, 2, 5
1, 7, 4, 8, 3, 5, 2, 6
1, 7, 4, 8, 2, 6, 3, 5
1, 7, 4, 8, 2, 5, 3, 6
1, 7, 4, 6, 5, 8, 2, 3
1, 7, 4, 6, 3, 8, 2, 5
1, 7, 4, 6, 3, 5, 2, 8
1, 7, 4, 6, 2, 8, 3, 5
1, 7, 4, 6, 2, 5, 3, 8
1, 7, 4, 5, 3, 8, 2, 6
1, 7, 4, 5, 3, 6, 2, 8
1, 7, 4, 5, 2, 8, 3, 6
1, 7, 4, 5, 2, 6, 3, 8
1, 7, 3, 8, 5, 6, 2, 4
1, 7, 3, 8, 4, 6, 2, 5
1, 7, 3, 8, 4, 5, 2, 6
1, 7, 3, 8, 2, 6, 4, 5
1, 7, 3, 8, 2, 5, 4, 6
1, 7, 3, 6, 5, 8, 2, 4
1, 7, 3, 6, 4, 8, 2, 5
1, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5, 2, 8
1, 7, 3, 6, 2, 8, 4, 5
1, 7, 3, 6, 2, 5, 4, 8
1, 7, 3, 5, 4, 8, 2, 6
1, 7, 3, 5, 4, 6, 2, 8
1, 7, 3, 5, 2, 8, 4, 6
1, 7, 3, 5, 2, 6, 4, 8
1, 7, 3, 4, 2, 8, 5, 6
1, 7, 3, 4, 2, 6, 5, 8
1, 7, 2, 8, 5, 6, 3, 4
1, 7, 2, 8, 4, 6, 3, 5
1, 7, 2, 8, 4, 5, 3, 6
1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 6, 4, 5
1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 5, 4, 6
1, 7, 2, 6, 5, 8, 3, 4
1, 7, 2, 6, 4, 8, 3, 5
1, 7, 2, 6, 4, 5, 3, 8
1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 8, 4, 5
1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4, 8
1, 7, 2, 5, 4, 8, 3, 6
1, 7, 2, 5, 4, 6, 3, 8
1, 7, 2, 5, 3, 8, 4, 6
1, 7, 2, 5, 3, 6, 4, 8
1, 7, 2, 4, 3, 8, 5, 6
1, 7, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8
1, 6, 5, 8, 4, 7, 2, 3
1, 6, 5, 8, 3, 7, 2, 4
1, 6, 5, 8, 3, 4, 2, 7
1, 6, 5, 8, 2, 7, 3, 4
1, 6, 5, 8, 2, 4, 3, 7
1, 6, 5, 7, 4, 8, 2, 3
1, 6, 5, 7, 3, 8, 2, 4
1, 6, 5, 7, 3, 4, 2, 8
1, 6, 5, 7, 2, 8, 3, 4
1, 6, 5, 7, 2, 4, 3, 8
1, 6, 4, 8, 5, 7, 2, 3
1, 6, 4, 8, 3, 7, 2, 5
1, 6, 4, 8, 3, 5, 2, 7
1, 6, 4, 8, 2, 7, 3, 5
1, 6, 4, 8, 2, 5, 3, 7
1, 6, 4, 7, 5, 8, 2, 3
1, 6, 4, 7, 3, 8, 2, 5
1, 6, 4, 7, 3, 5, 2, 8
1, 6, 4, 7, 2, 8, 3, 5
1, 6, 4, 7, 2, 5, 3, 8
1, 6, 4, 5, 3, 8, 2, 7
1, 6, 4, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8
1, 6, 4, 5, 2, 8, 3, 7
1, 6, 4, 5, 2, 7, 3, 8
1, 6, 3, 8, 5, 7, 2, 4
1, 6, 3, 8, 4, 7, 2, 5
1, 6, 3, 8, 4, 5, 2, 7
1, 6, 3, 8, 2, 7, 4, 5
1, 6, 3, 8, 2, 5, 4, 7
1, 6, 3, 7, 5, 8, 2, 4
1, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8, 2, 5
1, 6, 3, 7, 4, 5, 2, 8
1, 6, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4, 5
1, 6, 3, 7, 2, 5, 4, 8
1, 6, 3, 5, 4, 8, 2, 7
1, 6, 3, 5, 4, 7, 2, 8
1, 6, 3, 5, 2, 8, 4, 7
1, 6, 3, 5, 2, 7, 4, 8
1, 6, 3, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7
1, 6, 3, 4, 2, 7, 5, 8
1, 6, 2, 8, 5, 7, 3, 4
1, 6, 2, 8, 4, 7, 3, 5
1, 6, 2, 8, 4, 5, 3, 7
1, 6, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 5
1, 6, 2, 8, 3, 5, 4, 7
1, 6, 2, 7, 5, 8, 3, 4
1, 6, 2, 7, 4, 8, 3, 5
1, 6, 2, 7, 4, 5, 3, 8
1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 5
1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 5, 4, 8
1, 6, 2, 5, 4, 8, 3, 7
1, 6, 2, 5, 4, 7, 3, 8
1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 8, 4, 7
1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 7, 4, 8
1, 6, 2, 4, 3, 8, 5, 7
1, 6, 2, 4, 3, 7, 5, 8
1, 5, 4, 8, 6, 7, 2, 3
1, 5, 4, 8, 3, 7, 2, 6
1, 5, 4, 8, 3, 6, 2, 7
1, 5, 4, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6
1, 5, 4, 8, 2, 6, 3, 7
1, 5, 4, 7, 6, 8, 2, 3
1, 5, 4, 7, 3, 8, 2, 6
1, 5, 4, 7, 3, 6, 2, 8
1, 5, 4, 7, 2, 8, 3, 6
1, 5, 4, 7, 2, 6, 3, 8
1, 5, 4, 6, 3, 8, 2, 7
1, 5, 4, 6, 3, 7, 2, 8
1, 5, 4, 6, 2, 8, 3, 7
1, 5, 4, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8
1, 5, 3, 8, 6, 7, 2, 4
1, 5, 3, 8, 4, 7, 2, 6
1, 5, 3, 8, 4, 6, 2, 7
1, 5, 3, 8, 2, 7, 4, 6
1, 5, 3, 8, 2, 6, 4, 7
1, 5, 3, 7, 6, 8, 2, 4
1, 5, 3, 7, 4, 8, 2, 6
1, 5, 3, 7, 4, 6, 2, 8
1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4, 6
1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 6, 4, 8
1, 5, 3, 6, 4, 8, 2, 7
1, 5, 3, 6, 4, 7, 2, 8
1, 5, 3, 6, 2, 8, 4, 7
1, 5, 3, 6, 2, 7, 4, 8
1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 8, 6, 7
1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 7, 6, 8
1, 5, 2, 8, 6, 7, 3, 4
1, 5, 2, 8, 4, 7, 3, 6
1, 5, 2, 8, 4, 6, 3, 7
1, 5, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6
1, 5, 2, 8, 3, 6, 4, 7
1, 5, 2, 7, 6, 8, 3, 4
1, 5, 2, 7, 4, 8, 3, 6
1, 5, 2, 7, 4, 6, 3, 8
1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 6
1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 8
1, 5, 2, 6, 4, 8, 3, 7
1, 5, 2, 6, 4, 7, 3, 8
1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 8, 4, 7
1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8
1, 5, 2, 4, 3, 8, 6, 7
1, 5, 2, 4, 3, 7, 6, 8
1, 4, 3, 8, 6, 7, 2, 5
1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 7, 2, 6
1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 6, 2, 7
1, 4, 3, 8, 2, 7, 5, 6
1, 4, 3, 8, 2, 6, 5, 7
1, 4, 3, 7, 6, 8, 2, 5
1, 4, 3, 7, 5, 8, 2, 6
1, 4, 3, 7, 5, 6, 2, 8
1, 4, 3, 7, 2, 8, 5, 6
1, 4, 3, 7, 2, 6, 5, 8
1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 2, 7
1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 7, 2, 8
1, 4, 3, 6, 2, 8, 5, 7
1, 4, 3, 6, 2, 7, 5, 8
1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 8, 6, 7
1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7, 6, 8
1, 4, 2, 8, 6, 7, 3, 5
1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7, 3, 6
1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 6, 3, 7
1, 4, 2, 8, 3, 7, 5, 6
1, 4, 2, 8, 3, 6, 5, 7
1, 4, 2, 7, 6, 8, 3, 5
1, 4, 2, 7, 5, 8, 3, 6
1, 4, 2, 7, 5, 6, 3, 8
1, 4, 2, 7, 3, 8, 5, 6
1, 4, 2, 7, 3, 6, 5, 8
1, 4, 2, 6, 5, 8, 3, 7
1, 4, 2, 6, 5, 7, 3, 8
1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 8, 5, 7
1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 7, 5, 8
1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 8, 6, 7
1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 7, 6, 8
1, 3, 2, 8, 6, 7, 4, 5
1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 7, 4, 6
1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 6, 4, 7
1, 3, 2, 8, 4, 7, 5, 6
1, 3, 2, 8, 4, 6, 5, 7
1, 3, 2, 7, 6, 8, 4, 5
1, 3, 2, 7, 5, 8, 4, 6
1, 3, 2, 7, 5, 6, 4, 8
1, 3, 2, 7, 4, 8, 5, 6
1, 3, 2, 7, 4, 6, 5, 8
1, 3, 2, 6, 5, 8, 4, 7
1, 3, 2, 6, 5, 7, 4, 8
1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 8, 5, 7
1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 7, 5, 8
1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 8, 6, 7
1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 8
```

and there are 272 of them.